# Quartz: Show list of completed task

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I don't know if this is the best place to ask, but is it possible to query Quartz completed jobs ?

I can't find a solution, I already visited quartz website and googled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for information on historical run like start, end time (duration), params with which it was invoked you need to create your own table to persist those information.

The way i have done this in the past is

1. Created a new **JOB_LOG** table
2. Created a Custom Quartz Job Listener by extending **JobListenerSupport** http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/listeners/JobListenerSupport.html
3. Depending on your requirement add your persistence logic to

   ```
   @Override
   public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
           //insert here
   }

   @Override
   public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
           //insert here
   }
   ```